# Omit nodes in XML based on Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Using C# ***[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)***

I'm trying to omit the first and last nodes in the following XML.

I'm trying to process each node between `<node id="2" one="start">` and `<node id="4" one="finish">`

```
<root>
  <node id="1">
    <element two="3"/>
    <element two="7"/>
  </node>
  <node id="2" one="start">
    <element two="1"/>
    <element two="2"/>
  </node>
  <node id="3">
    <element two="4"/>
    <element two="4"/>
    <element two="4"/>
    <element two="2"/>
    <element two="6"/>
  </node>
  <node id="4">
    <element two="3"/>
    <element two="7"/>
  </node>
  <node id="5" one="finish">
    <element two="3"/>
    <element two="7"/>
  </node>
  <node id="6">
    <element two="3"/>
    <element two="7"/>
  </node>
<root>
```

Is there a to standard approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sequence of `XElement`s and you want to filter them based on your condition, I don't think there is anything built-in in LINQ to do exactly that (there is `SkipWhile()` and `TakeWhile()` that do something similar).

I think what you should do is to create a generic extension method that filter a collection based on first and last condition, something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetBetween<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> firstPredicate, Func<T, bool> lastPredicate)
{
    bool foundFirst = false;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!foundFirst)
            foundFirst = firstPredicate(item);

        if (foundFirst)
        {
            yield return item;

            if (lastPredicate(item))
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
elements.GetBetween(
    e => (string)e.Attribute("one") == "start",
    e => (string)e.Attribute("one") == "finish")
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with some very simple logic to handle this.

```
bool processFlag = false;
```

Toggling this boolean from `false` to `true` when the node.element.attribute = "start" then back to `false` when the = "finish" did the trick!